# How to conditionally use React Native elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I need to use different wrappers to render the screen based on a certain condition.
Example, I have a situation where I need to wrap the content in a view

```
      <View>
         <Text> </Text>
         <View> </View>
         { and other elements here }
      </View>
```

But in a different scenario, I need the View to be Content from nativeBase.
if useContent variable is true, then render everything using Content as a wrapper, else use View.
How would I best do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ternary operator to help you conditionally render.

```
render() {
  const useContent = true;

  return useContent ? (
    <Content>
      <Text></Text>
      <View></View>
    </Content>
  ) : (
    <View>
      <Text></Text>
      <View></View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

It may also be better to extract these two pieces into their own components. Just so your component file doesn't become too large and maintainability starts to be a concern. *Edit: If you want to keep the children of the component the same and just the wrapping element to change create a second component that renders children:*

```
class WrappingElement extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children, useContent } = this.props;

    return useContent ? (
      <Content>{children}</Content>
    ) : (
      <View>{children}</View>
    )
  }
}

class Foo extends Component {
  render() {
    <WrappingElement useContent={false}>
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
      <View></View>
    </WrappingElement>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The entire content that needs to go is too large and dependent on the screen, is there a way to have a function that would allow me to use Content and View interchangeably ?
example: const contentorView = () => useContent ? <Content> : <View> 
And then use that instead. But I'm not sure this way would work.

Comment: you could do the same thing but the children of the tag can be a single component. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<View>
     booleanCondition1() && <Text> </Text>
     booleanCondition2() && <View> </View>
     booleanConditionN() && { and other elements here }
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View>
  {condition == true ?
    (
      <Text> </Text>
      <View> </View>
    )
    :
    (
      { and other elements here }
    )
  }
</View>
```